# Sending email but not receiving - GoDaddy VPS server and Cloudflare

Tags: email, cloudflare, incoming-mail

I have cloudflared my site which is hosted on GoDaddy.

I also set up an email for this site:

info@domain.com

It sends email fine.

No incoming email is received.

On Cloudflare it says: Add an MX record for your root domain so that mail can reach @trackpython.com addresses.

Update: I have added the correct MX record on CLOUDFLARE - but still no luck.

What else do I need to do to resolve the problem of no incoming email.

The GoDaddy CAdvisor says the "email routing" is wrong...but offers no further help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps someone:

There were two things that I needed to do to get this working:

1. on Godaddy - email routing: I had to change this to "LOCAL MAIL EXCHANGER"
2. Cloudflare:
   I had to set up two records on CLOUDFLARE in order for this to work

**#1**

Record type: MX
domainname.com
mail.domainname.com
1 hr
DNS only

**#2**

Record Type: A
mail
xx.xxx.xxx.xx (IP ADDRESS of SERVER)
Auto
Proxied

**Worked!**

Prior to this, as mentioned in the question, I had set up the DNS in GoDaddy's WHM (set the name servers) and the created an A record pointing to the server in the DNS Management tab for the domain.

Comment: ** mail.domainname.com ** is this an outgoing or incoming server?